# OS X run rsync under sudo using ssh_config

Tags: macos, ssh, rsync

I want to set up an automatic `rsync` job to backup a bunch of user accounts on my OS X machine to a linux fileserver. I have set up password-free ssh from my account to another machine, and it works great, so I tried using this command:

```
sudo rsync -avz /Users/jbloggs myserv:/var/Backup/
```

where `myserv` is an alias set up in my `~/.ssh/config`. The problem I have is that I have to use sudo to get that command to work -- under my personal account I don't have access to the other users' home directories to copy files for backup. That command works fine on my own account without sudo, but when I run under sudo it's not looking at my `~/.ssh/config` any more (so it complains about "unknown host myserv").

How can I get the rsync running under sudo to still look at my personal `~/.ssh/config`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
ssh -i /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa -F /Users/myuser/.ssh/config login@host
```

to let ssh use your config / key files. Use "-v" to check which file it is using. You could also copy your configuration / id to /var/root/.ssh, which will be used by default when using ssh via sudo.

To pass these options to rsync, you have to set the "--rsh" / "-e" like this:

```
rsync -e "ssh -i ... -F ..."
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. In the general case (if this wasn't a home computer) then copying my ssh_config over to /var/root would be a security hole, no? It means that anyone with sudo access could connect to the remote host using that config?

Comment: Well, the security hole is inherent, since you want to batch-copy files to the remote computer and use an unencrypted private key for that. Anyone with sudo access to a computer where your unencrypted key is stored will be able to ssh into the remote pc. (And with some work also the encrypted key)

Comment: So the best way to go is to generate a new key which only has access to the backup account - so in case your key gets lost only this account is compromised.